# Button not responding/not binding in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have two functions in Javascript shown below:

```
function Add(){

    $("#tbl tbody").append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><button class=\"btn btnSave\"><i class=\"icon-ok\"></i></button><button class=\"btn btnDelete\"><i class=\"icon-remove\"></i></button></td>"+
        "</tr>"

    );

    $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);      
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);

};
```

and

```
function Delete(){ 
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); 
    par.remove(); 
};
```

and finally these two lines after the functions:

```
$(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
$("#btnAdd").bind("click", Add);
```

The function *Add()* adds a new row to the table with id **tbl**. The last column in a newly added row has two buttons **btnSave** and **btnDelete**. **btnDelete** is supposed to delete that particular row as is evident from the *Delete()* function. (I have not started to implement the 'save' function yet). But, whenever I click the 'Delete' button, nothing happens. Is there a problem with the code?

I am using [*bootstrap css*](http://getbootstrap.com/) for my UI.

Function *Add()* works properly by the way.

**Edit:** Here is a screen capture. The highlighted button *cross* is not working.
[image: Screen Capture]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's may caused by duplicate event binding, try this code :

```
function Add(){

    $("#tbl tbody").append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text'/></td>"+
        "<td><button class=\"btn btnSave\"><i class=\"icon-ok\"></i></button><button class=\"btn btnDelete\"><i class=\"icon-remove\"></i></button></td>"+
        "</tr>"

    );
};

// it will also be affected for new objects
$(document).on("click", ".btnSave", Save);
$(document).on("click", ".btnDelete", Delete);
```

Comment: Still not working!I have added: `$(document).on("click", "#btnAdd", Add);` also. Is it a problem because I have used a separate javascript file for the functions and the html code is in a different file?

Comment: It would be better to do the binding from `#tbl tbody` rather than `document`; that way the `btnSave` and `btnDelete` classes can be reused in other contexts.

Comment: yes you need to turn all your functions to be global, for example for Delete function => window.Delete = Delete ...

Comment: @aimadnet I made the functions global by doing this: `window.Delete = function(){....}` , but it is not working! Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: You've checked your console if there is a js error after you clicked the button? You can use Firebug for that.